# How do I integrate the Twilio deactivated phone number API into SalesForce using Apex?

Tags: apex

I need to integrate the Twilio deactivated phone number API into SalesForce (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/deactivated-phone-numbers)

This API provides a .txt file with a list of phone numbers that have been deactivated.

My idea is to take this file and cross-reference it with my SalesForce database to see if any of the numbers in my database have been deactivated. If a match is found, a checkbox custom field (isNumberDeactivated?) needs to be checked and a date custom field (deactivated as of) needs to be filled with the current date

It has to be done using Apex.

Does anyone have any code that might help? I haven't ever done SalesForce Apex development but would like to learn. I have heard Apex is very similar to JS. I have the JS to retrieve the file of the deactivated numbers:

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.messaging.v1.Deactivations;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Example {
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Deactivations deactivations = Deactivations.fetcher()
            .setDate(LocalDate.of(2020, 9, 5)).fetch();

        System.out.println(deactivations.getRedirectTo());
    }
}
```

but I have no idea how to take that file as a .txt file and parse the database for matches then updating the records if a match is found

Comment: `I have heard Apex is very similar to JS`, not quite. The better comparison is that it's similar to _Java_ rather than JavaScript (a.k.a. ECMAScript). Looking at the Twilio docs some more, the format is ["e.164"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164)

Comment: @DerekF ok, e.164 format also needs to be done, there's another Twilio API that does that (https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/tutorials/validation-and-formatting#format-an-international-phone-number). Do you think you could write some code that would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a brief look at the Twilio documentation, the `redirectTo` that you get requires another callout to get the actual data (which is in "e.164" format, with each number being on a separate line).

Apex works in UTF-8 (of which ASCII is a subset). It's not made clear whether Twilio uses Windows-style line breaks (`\r\n`) or Unix-style line breaks (`\n`).

At any rate though, the general process here (keeping in mind that we're encouraged to work on *collections* instead of on individual records) would look something like:

- Make the first callout to the Twilio API

  - Using the `Http`, `HttpReqest` and `HttpResponse` classes
  - Keep in mind that Salesforce only allows us 6 MB of heap space in a synchronous transaction
  - See [HTTP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) in the Apex documentation for a basic example
  - You will need to add a [Remote Site Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.configuring_remoteproxy.htm&type=5) for Twilio to successfully make the callout
- Get the `RedirectTo` url
- Make the second callout to the Twilio API to get the actual phone number data (e.164 format)
- Use `String.split()` (part of the `String` class, [relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm)) to take the resulting .txt data and put it into a `List<String>`

  - The regex that Twilio provides is a good start, if you use it in a regex group
  - Regex in Apex generally requires doubling the backslashes
  - So the regex string to use in Apex (for splitting) would be `\\r?\\n`
  - The `Phone` field type in Salesforce is a `String` in Apex with some restrictions (numeric, and "+", and "-")
- Perform a SOQL (Salesforce Object Query Language) query on an SObject and use a [variable bind](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) in the `WHERE` clause

  - e.g.

    ```java
    List<String> twilioDeactivatedTNList = twilioHttpResponse.getBody().split('\\r?\\n');
    List<Contact> affectedContacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Phone IN :twilioDeactivatedTNList];
    ```

From there, you can

- Iterate over the SObject records

  - `for(Contact myContact :affectedContacts){ /* code here */ }`
- Set your two custom fields (`isNumberDeactivated__c`, `deactivatedAsOf__c`) using dot notation just like pretty much every other OOP language
- Perform a DML `update` (e.g. `update affectedContacts;`) to persist the changes

Comment: Ok, what would the final code look like? As I said, I have no idea what I'm doing here as I've never done anything like this before, I'm new to SalesForce

Comment: @JasonLevine I can't write a concrete example because you haven't specified which SObject you're trying to work with. Even if you did though, I'm not going to write a copy/paste solution. I'm here to help, to educate, but not do work for free. I've provided an outline and links to relevant documentation and pointed out the main pain points you'd run into in Apex. If you've worked in other OOP languages, then Apex should be relatively easy to pick up. Searching for `<class name here> apex` in your search engine of choice will point you to the fairly good official documentation.

Comment: @JasonLevine If you still aren't really comfortable with Apex, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started. SE sites (like this one) are more about narrow, specific, authoritative Q&A. Trailhead is more step-by-step. The [Apex Basics module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) would be a good place to start if you have existing knowledge of programming. If you can give this a bit more of an attempt yourself, it'd be good material for another question which I (or another regular contributor) could answer.